# QTcpServer can only be accessed through localhost

Tags: c++, qt, ip, qtcpserver

My computer's IP on the local network is `192.168.0.100`, I start my QTcpServer with

```
if (!tcpServer->listen(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 1234)) {
```

When I try to connect to it with `netcat 192.168.0.100 1234`, the connection is refused, but `netcat localhost 1234` succeeds.

At the same time, if I listen with `netcat -l -p 1234`, I can connect on both `192.168.0.100` and `localhost` without any problem.

This has me scratching my head, why is it happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to accept connections from the outside, you have to listen on `0.0.0.0`, not on `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`. The latter will only allow connections coming from the same machine. It's also the value of `QHostAddress::LocalHost`.

So change the first argument to `QHostAddress::Any` and it should work.

Comment: Up till now I always thought that listening on localhost meant that you get all connections that reach the local machine, so I kind of thought that `QHostAddress::LocalHost` is the same as `QHostAddress::Any`. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: Yeah this is a frequent cause of confusion. Listening on `127.0.0.1` is intended for cases where you do *not* want to allow a connection from the outside, like when you're running a DB server on the same machine as your web server and don't want to expose it etc.

Comment: It seems it goes the other way around, too. I tried with `tcpServer->listen(QHostAddress("192.168.56.1"), 1234))` and now it won't accept `netcat localhost 1234`, only `netcat 192.168.56.1`.

Comment: I feel like it might be add value to describe the difference between listening on a specific interface vs all interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

`localhost` is on a separate network interface

you can use `QHostAddress::Any` to listen for external connections